# JavaScript-new object can have prototype link to another object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have 3 questions about the following code that I have found in a text book about JavaScript called "JavaScript: The Good Parts".

It says that when we make a new object, we can select the object that should be its prototype.

Part 1: lets say we have the following object

```
var person = {
    first_name: "Tim",
    last_name: "Thompson",
    middel_name: "Jack",
    nick_name: "GoldTeeth",
    age:30
  };
```

Part 2: then we are going to add the Create function to Object using following code

```
Object.create = function(o){
    var F = function(){};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F(); 
}
```

and then later we can map any new object's prototype to "person" using `Object.create()` function

part 3: example//

```
  var another_person = Object.create(person);
  alert(another_person.first_name); //Tim
```

1. why in the body of create function why we assign F to a function
2. and at the end return a new F()
3. why in part 3 we assign another_person to a function

I understand that in JavaScript functions are object but I can't follow the logic. Could anyone help me?

Comment: *"we assign F to a function "* No, we assign a function to `F`. *"we assign another_person to a function "* No, we assign the result of `Object.create` to `another_person`, which is an object. `new F` creates an object. I think you should read up on the `new` keyword and how it works together with the `prototype` property of the function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_Objects, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 0):

When you have a code like this:

```
var foo = bar;
```

then your **variable** called `foo` will get the **value** `bar`. So it is `bar` assigned to `foo`, *not* `foo` assigned to `bar`, therefore you have some misconceptions in your question.

As about the code posted. The first part creates an object and assigns it to `person`. The second part assigns a function to `Object.create`. The function creates a new empty function and assigns it to `F`. When this is done, the parameter called `o` is assigned to `F`'s `prototype`. Since `F` has a `prototype`, it can be instantiated and a new instance of `F` is returned. The third part is a test code. It takes `person` and using `Object.create` instantiates a new `person`.